# Batch File... Close openfiles

Tags: pdf, batch-file, automation, taskkill

I searched for 2 days. Now I am here and hope to get help. 
I am trying to "kill (close)" a file automatically. 
For example:

@echo off
taskkill /IM Acrord32.exe

Thats works fine. The only problem is, that it closes every PDF file. But I only want to close a specific file. 
Maybe through path.

So, i hope anyone can help me. 
(It do not have to be a Batch Script that closes this PDF file, it can also be a Tool or something else) But it has to close the file AUTOMATICALLY.

I hope you understand me. I am not English.

Thanks so far. M.L.

Comment: Do you want to close a specific PDF with a given filename, whenever it is opened?  Can you explain the task further?

Answer (score 0):

For such, you would need to "tell" Acrobat Reader to close file. But AFAIK Acrobat Reader doesn't expose any API for remote control.

Only choice I see is send a Ctrl+F4 to Reader, but from command line is not possible (at least with standard commands).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what you mean, but You ask for a script that closes Acrord32 process and it automatically. My script does, but only for the processes that have been "suspended" and too much demand on the processor.

There is then no need for any changes to the registry, parameters or settings Acrobat Reader. Batch script prepared by default to automaticaly kill process Acrord32.exe and to this end has been designed, but the script can be used to close as any other process too burdensome system, which was suspended when the script calls to the appropriate parameter. If this parameter contains a long name with a space, you must enclose the parameter in quotation marks. Inside the script, to the beginning of the several parameters can be determined, for example. Time of suspension, the time of re-checking, or where the report is to be created (LOG). The script closes all processes meet the criteria for any user, of course, not the system that can not be closed. Can be useful on the server, the work of many users.  The script is optimized in order to minimize itself burdened processor.

Thank You

```
@echo off
REM Automatic closing Acrobat Reader or other process parameter specified in the call, which too much high the CPU
REM Preparing:  Artur Zgadzaj
REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET REPEAT_TIME_VERIFICATION_[seconds]=7
SET IDLE_TIME_[seconds]=5

SET LOG_FOLDER=C:\UTIL\LOG



REM    # # # #      CHECKING OR IS STARTED AS ADMINISTRATOR     # # # # #

FSUTIL | findstr /I "volume" > nul&if not errorlevel 1  goto Administrator_OK

cls
echo ************************************
echo ***    RUN  AS  ADMINISTRATOR    ***
echo ************************************
echo.
echo.
echo Call up just as the Administrator. Abbreviation can be done to the script and set:
echo.
echo      Shortcut ^> Advanced ^> Run as Administrator
echo.
echo.
echo Alternatively, a single run "Run as Administrator"
echo or in the Schedule tasks with highest privileges
pause > nul
goto:eof
:Administrator_OK

SET WD=day
if "%~1"==""  (SET Close_Process=AcroRd32.exe)  else  (SET "Close_Process=%~1")
MD %LOG_FOLDER% 2>NUL
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:again
cls
echo Automatic closing %Close_Process%, which are charged to the processor too ...&echo.&echo.

FOR /F "tokens=2,7,8 delims=,"  %%A IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /v /FO CSV^|find /I ^"%Close_Process%^"') DO (

  SET PROC=%%C
  SET PROC=!PROC:"=!

  FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=:"  %%s IN ("!PROC!") DO (SET PR=%%t
      if "!PR:~0,1!"=="0"  (SET /A PROC_TIME=%%s*60+!PR:~1,1!)  else  (SET /A PROC_TIME=%%s*60+!PR:~0,2!))

  if !PROC_TIME! GTR %IDLE_TIME_[seconds]%   (
      SET PID=%%A
      SET PID=!PID:"=!

      %SystemRoot%\system32\taskkill.exe /PID !PID! /F

      SET B=%%B
      SET B=!B:%USERDOMAIN%\=!
      SET B=!B:%COMPUTERNAME%\=!
      SET Process_User=!B:"=!

      if not "!DATE_WD!"=="%DATE%" ((FOR /F "tokens=1" %%W IN ('POWERSHELL GET-DATE -format dddd') DO SET WD=%%W)&&SET DATE_WD=%DATE%)
      echo %TIME:~0,8%    ^(Hanging:  !PROC:~-5!^)         !Process_User! >>"%LOG_FOLDER%\%DATE:-=.%  ^(!WD:~0,3!^)  Close_%Close_Process%.TXT"
      )
  )

TIMEOUT /T %REPEAT_TIME_VERIFICATION_[seconds]% > nul
goto again
```